# "Kit de Unhas": de onde vem esta expressão?

Tags: significado, expressões, expressões-idiomáticas, origem, neologismos

Não sendo a primeira vez que me deparo com ela, hoje, após assistir a um vídeo de uma manobra impressionante feita por uma tripulação de um veleiro, ouvi a expressão: "Que **kit de unhas** impressionante!".

Outro exemplo de utilização, [que encontrei no Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/Fretem-ma): "Valeu-lhe o **kit d’unhas** e alguma sorte para as coisas não terem acabado da pior forma."

Pelo contexto das situações nas quais já ouvi a expressão, calculo que esteja associada a uma combinação de competências e utilização das ferramentas ao redor da melhor forma (fruto, ou não, destas estarem adequadas ao utilizador/à utilização).

No entanto, não encontro informações acerca da origem da expressão, nem mesmo se a entendo da forma correta.

Comment: Deve ser uma expressão muito nova.  Uma busca no Google Books, tanto para "kit de unhas" quanto para "kit d'unhas" gerou zero resultado.

Answer (score 5):

O *kit* é um neologismo da lingua Inglesa cujo uso se tornou muito comum na língua Portuguesa a partir da segunda metade da primeira década de 2000. O uso da palavra *kit* tornou-se tão vulgarizado que se aplica de forma corrente a quase tudo.

Depois a preposição *de* por **contração** (a contração é processo normal na gramática) pode aparecer contraído sem a vogal *e* ligado ao substantivo por uma apóstrofe.

Finalmente, se quiser saber a origem da utilização da expressão "kit de unhas" ou da forma contraída "kit d'unhas" pode pesquiser no google usando aspas e ordenar por data.

Fiz a pesquisa no google, e parece que as primeiras utilizações -da forma contraída- foram no mundo dos desportos motorizados por volta de 2005. A primeira ocorrência no google foi num fórum Português de desportos motorizados. Pode usar a pesquisa aqui: [ver no google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22kit%20d%27unhas%22&lr=&hl=pt-PT&as_qdr=all&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F1%2F2010&tbm=)

O sentido da expressão é a palavra "unhas" em Portugal poder ser cordialmente usada como sinónimo de saber conduzir bem um carro (no sentido de: "ter unhas para segurar o volante"). Juntamente com o uso da palavra *kit* ser muito vulgarizada no mundo automóvel para denominar um conjunto de peças -habitualmente vendido em conjunto- para modificar veículos motorizados.

Foi o caso de juntar um neologismo corrente, com um sinónimo bem humorado, e fazer a contração da preposição que une as duas palavras. O valor humorístico reside em obrigar o ouvinte a pensar no sentido da expressão, remetendo para encontrar a semântica algo rebuscada do sinónimo unhas, dado não ser d'uso frequente.

Será este o sentido para além do mais óbvio que seria um conjunto de acessórios para manicure.

Comment: "O sentido da expressão é a palavra "unhas" em Portugal poder ser cordialmente usada como sinónimo de saber conduzir bem um carro" - @bad_coder tens alguma fonte para isto?

Comment: @Rye [a expressão tem alguma frequência entre amantes dos desportos motorizados.](https://www.google.com/search?&q=unhas+rally)